# ecg raw signal realtime filtering and removing baseline wander

Tags: synchronization, filtering, real-time, baselineremoval

I am currently  trying to achieve stimuli synchronization to cardiac systole and diastole.

I have BIOPAC MP45 (education version) and BHAPI.
I've succeeded in getting the realtime signal from MP45 using BHAPI,
however, I have trouble finding peaks realtime,

I have tried with many packages that are open to the public,
but they all seem to deal with filtered and baselined signals not raw signals

could anyone help me with realtime filtering and removing the baseline wander ?
especially, it would be best if I can set the signals into a R-wave mode,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h66SH.png)

this is the raw signal i'm receiving

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBDmQ.png)

and this is the signal shape I want to achieve.  (R-wave mode)

I have come across many algorithms that process the signals after acquisition, and I have no probelm applying them after acquisition, but what I'd like to achieve is real time.

In detail, if I have realtime data input with a sliding window size of 25 data points
I need to detect exactly where the peak is within that sliding window.

Thanks so much in advance..

I've tried working with the rtpeaks python package, and the recent cuspis matlab library..